# 恋 written as 恋ひ and 恋ふ?

Tags: kanji, song-lyrics, video-games, jōyō-kanji

A song in Final Fantasy 14 named Sunrise has a line listed as such, from an official source:

> 清らに優し　恋ひ恋ふ吾が君よ
> ⇒きよらにやさし　こいこうあがきみよ

What are the purposes of the い(ひ) and う(ふ) being written outside of the kanji following it, (the dictionary I use most frequently lists 恋, strictly as こい, but makes no mention of 恋い or 恋う, nor these 恋ひ and 恋ふ variants.) and why is the version containing kanji using ひ and ふ afterwards?

My best guess as far as the latter part of my question is that it is an old form, but that wouldn't explain why the current kanji reasing envelopes the い and う to begin with.

Comment: What dictionary are you using? Here's one that has 恋う, and also lists classical spelling. https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%81%8B%E3%81%86

Comment: @Leebo the Midori application for iPhone. It wasn't free, so assumed it would have some kind of inherent credibility. :c

Answer (score 2):

Modern noun [恋]{こい} ("love", generally referring more specifically to romantic or carnal love) is derived as the [連用形]{れんようけい} (also known as the "continuative form" or "stem form") of verb [恋う]{こう}.

The historical kana spelling for the verb ([歴史的仮名遣い]{れきしてきかなづかい}, see also the Wikipedia articles in [Japanese](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%B4%E5%8F%B2%E7%9A%84%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E9%81%A3) and [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_kana_orthography)) was [恋ふ]{こふ} instead, and the [連用形]{れんようけい} was [恋ひ]{こひ}.

→ With the [送り仮名]{おくりがな}, we know that [恋ひ]{こひ} is intended not as the noun, but rather as the [連用形]{れんようけい} of the verb.  And [恋ふ]{こふ} must be understood as the verb.

⇒ As [恋ひ恋ふ]{こひこふ}, this could be parsed as a compound verb, and as a reduplication (where the same element shows up multiple times), it comes across as an intensifier: [吾が君]{わがきみ} doesn't just *love*, they *really really love*.

- Regarding the historical shift in kana spellings, Middle Japanese apparently pronounced the final ふ and ひ etc. closer to how they are spelled -- so the verb [恋ふ]{こふ} was pronounced as something like *kofu*.  Over time, the medial (mid-word) //h// and //f// sounds [lenited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenition) (softened) and vanished (almost) everywhere except before //a//, where we now have modern わ.  This is why [買う]{かう} gets that //w// that appears in [買]{か}**[わ]{●}**ない.
  For some more about this historical shift, read [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/82475/why-does-fu-changes-to-pu-while-its-not-started-with-h/82477#82477).